# header stretches instead of

Tags: html, css

To make a long story short, the header class should be a black line across the entire screen. In HTML it will be a list. The list's children will be styled as buttons and should begin after the first 20% of the page. Somewhere along the line this is going terribly wrong, because:

1. The list children aren't styled at all (the margin)
2. The page stretches itself a lot.

Here is the entire source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
    html, body {
         padding: 0;
         background-color:#FFFCF2;
         margin: 0 auto;
         }

        .header {
          list-style:none;  
        width:100%;
        height:65px;
        font-size:3%;   
        background: black;
         }

        .header:first-child {
        margin-left:20%;
        }

    .headerChild {
        margin-left:0;
        float:left;
         height:65px;
         width:10%;
         background: white;
    }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
         <ul class="header">
        <li class="headerChild"></li>
        <li class="headerChild"></li>
        <li class="headerChild"></li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the children aren't styled at all?"  How are they supposed to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues that I see:

- `.header:first-child` is applied to the `<ul>`, so change it to `.header>li:first-child` and that will target the first `<li>` and set its left margin
- You set your font size to 3% in `.header` and the `<li>` inherit that, make sure that is what you want
- set `padding:0` on `.header` as well to prevent the horizontal scrollbars.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/Lmy3y/1/) for you to look at. I've put red borders around the `<li>` and text so you can see them.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your CSS with the following:

```
html, body {
     padding: 0;
     background-color:#FFFCF2;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    list-style:none;  
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    font-size:3%;   
    background: black;
    padding-left: 20%;
}

.header:first-child {       
}

.headerChild {
    margin-left:0;
    float:left;
     height:65px;
     width:10%;
     background: white;      
}
```